Paginate API response object with multiple sub arrays
I have this response from a REST API service:
{
    "Business": [
        {
            "link": "...",
            "og": "...",
            "source": "...",
            "source_icon": "...",
            "title": "..."
        },
    ],
    "Entertainment": [
        {
            "link": "...",
            "og": "...",
            "source": "...",
            "source_icon": "...",
            "title": "..."
        },
    ],
    "Health": [
        {
            "link": "...",
            "og": "...",
            "source": "...",
            "source_icon": "...",
            "title": "..."
        },
    ],
    "Science": [
        {
            "link": "...",
            "og": "...",
            "source": "...",
            "source_icon": "...",
            "title": "..."
        },
    ],
    "Sports": [
        {
            "link": "...",
            "og": "...",
            "source": "...",
            "source_icon": "...",
            "title": "..."
        },

    ],
    "Technology": [
        {
            "link": "...",
            "og": "...",
            "source": "...",
            "source_icon": "...",
            "title": "..."
        },
    ],
    "US": [
        {
            "link": "...",
            "og": "...",
            "source": "...",
            "source_icon": "...",
            "title": "..."
        },
    ],
    "World": [
        {
            "link": "...",
            "og": "...",
            "source": "...",
            "source_icon": "...",
            "title": "..."
        },
    ]
}

In my Vue app I've created this function to get the data and I'm using a ref to manage them inside my application:
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import { NewsResponse } from '@/utils';

const baseURL = '...';

const isLoading = ref<boolean>(true);
const newsFeed = ref<NewsResponse>();
//const pageSize = 12;


onMounted(() => {
  fetchNewsFeed();
});

const fetchNewsFeed = () => {
  axios.get(baseURL)
    .then((res) => {
      newsFeed.value = res.data;
      isLoading.value = false;
      console.log('api response\n',newsFeed.value);
      
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
}

Since each category into the response object will be an array, at the moment I'm managing it in my template using a v-for loop, all is working fine, but each array can have from 46 to 50 elements inside and this after looping the elements will result in a long age to scroll.
 <div 
    class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4 py-3"
    v-for="(articlesCollection, cat) in newsFeed" 
    :key="cat">
    <div 
      class="card shadow-lg w-fit my-2 rounded-md"
      v-for="(article, index) in articlesCollection"
      :key="index"
    >
      <figure>
        <img class="w-full h-48" :src="article.og">
      </figure>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="badge badge-primary text-white">
          {{ cat }}
        </div>
        <a 
          class="no-underline" 
          :href="article.link"
        >
          <h1 class="card-title text-sm">
            {{ article.title }}
          </h1>
        </a>
        <div class="card-actions">
          <div class="badge badge-outline">
            {{ article.source }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

My idea is to have 12 elements in a grid of 4 element for each single row and when the user reach the end of the page load new elements like the infinite scroll will do normally. How I can correctly paginate the elements in this case? I've looked at this question, but in my case not sure if I can use slice, due to the fact that I will have multiple array inside the response object.
UPDATE
I've implemented this solution to add inside each object the category and seems work, but probaly not the best way to flat the array. Any suggestion is accepted
      let tmpCat = [];
      let tmpItems = [];
      Object.entries(rawData).forEach((cat, i) => {
        tmpCat.push(cat[0]);
        cat[1].forEach((item) => {
          item['category'] = tmpCat[i];
          tmpItems.push(item);
        })
      });


If you cannot change the API way of doing things, then you should probably flatten all the arrays into 1 before passing it to your infinite scroll/pagination, might be too messy to deal with all the arrays otherwise.

@kissu unfortunately it's a third part service and I can only use this response, the main problem is that I need to mantain the categories to distinguish the related items

I would still flatten everything into 1 array and add the key (eg: "Technology") to each object inside aka having it on the same level as og, title, source etc.

seems ok, this will require to me to iterate each single category right and push the new key inside the object?

Yes! Will make it far easier down the road to handle your template logic etc. Might need quite some work on the client-side but you could maybe do it somehow ahead of time or use some kind of backend proxy to avoid that payload structure change on the client.

need to do a test, after this how I will add the infinite scroll, can I use the slice function on the flat array I will have?Can you show an example please?

Depends on the size of your data and how important is the performance on your page. Loading a huge array and slicing it on the client-side might be quite heavy. I don't have an example to share but you probably can find 10 ways of flattening into 1 array with some quick search. Once you have your single array + added the category key to your object, then you can focus on having some infinite scroll + performance. Some of my previous answers could be helpful for the performance/scroll part: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+infinite+scroll

mainly I need to figure out how to push correctly the category into the single ies of the arrays
